# Transfer funds to "heir" - Possible?

Tags: plutus, cardano-address

Is it possible to write a smart contract in cardano - without off-chain solutions - that would hold funds until a specified date (or block height), and if I didn't interact with that smart contract until that date/block it would send the funds to other wallets, that would be hard-coded into the SC?

If so, how? And is it possible to stake funds that are locked in a smart contract?

My guess is that it's not possible to make the smart contract know the tip of the chain, so a SC like that wouldn't be doable without an off-chain companion. Am I right? And is it also true for other chains and languages?

Answer (score 2):

No, because there is no mechanism to build and submit transactions on-chain.

The closest option to what you want would be to create a simple timelocking script and send funds to the script's address. However, to unlock the funds, a transaction will need to be constructed off-chain and submitted once the slot boundary has passed.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if this would be feasible in other networks? Is it a Cardano limitation, or something common to every blockchain?